# Adjective or adverbs

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

Sometimes, I don't know which word to use in my sentence (adj or adv). For example, in below sentences, which is right?

> He ran too quick.

and

> He ran too quickly.

And in general, when should I use adverb and adjective?

Comment: Suggested reading: [Flat adverbs are exceeding fine | Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/flat-adverbs-are-exceeding-fine), or if you prefer something in video format, ["Drive Safe: In Praise of Flat Adverbs" with Emily Brewster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/video/drive-safe-in-praise-of-flat-adverbs)

Answer (score 2):

The correct sentence is:

> He ran too quickly.

Lets look at the adjective/adverb combination `beautiful/beautifully`

> **Taylor Swift** is beautiful.

In this example we can see that the subject (Taylor Swift) is being referenced by the adjective beautiful.

> Taylor Swift **sings** beautifully.

In this example we can see that the verb (sings) is being referenced by the adverb beautifully.

A general rule of thumb is that linking verbs (be, feels, smells, seems, etc) use adjectives.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence use: He ran too quickly. 
Generally, you should use an adverb as it is describing the verb, for example, quickly is describing the verb to run.

Answer (score 1):

An adjective describes nouns.

An adverb describes an adjective, a verb, or another adverb.